# TransactionException Hibernate when MySQL is closed

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, try-catch

Here's a little code fragment:

```
try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            u = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, user.getUserName());
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
        catch(TransactionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            addFieldError("userName","No connection. Try again later");
        }
```

Whit this code fragment I would like to see if my database is running or not and I would like to know why Eclipse skips the catch segment. When my database is closed without this try-catch method Eclipse gives me an error(TransactionException....).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a transaction to just get the userName, also, you're leaving the session open when the try block fails.

And of course you get an error without the try/catch, you need to handle the exception, for this case you should catch a HibernateException.

if you really need the transaction, this is how you handle it:

```
Session session = null;
Transaction transaction=null;
try{
    session = HibernateUtil.getSession();       
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    u = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, user.getUserName());
    transaction.commit();
}catch(HibernateException he){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    addFieldError("userName","No connection. Try again later");
    if(transaction !=null)
        transaction.rollback();
}finally{
    if(session.isOpen())
        session.close();
}
```

Comment: It's not working. It just stands and loads... Doesn't give me an error or anything. How can I just simply check then (with try/catch) if my database is up and running?